# Neo4j JS driver cypher "WHERE" clause not working with parameters

Tags: typescript, neo4j, cypher

I have a simple function that matches a User to an Id and should create a relationship like this.

```
const createRelation = (userId: string, todoId: string, relationship: string) => {
    return session.run(
        'MATCH (a:User),(b:Todo)' +
        'WHERE a.id = $userId AND b.id = $todoId' +
        'CREATE (b)-[r:$relationship]->(a)' +
        'RETURN r',
        {
            userId: userId,
            todoId: todoId,
            relationship: relationship,
        }
    );
}
```

This code does not throw any errors, but it also does not create a relationship. If I set the values for `userId` and `todoId`manually, e.g. to `"1"`, it works fine! Am I using the parameters wrong? If so, how? (I also already tried setting the relationship type manually, no relationship gets created if I use the parameters.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can't parametrize [for these kinds of constructs.](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/)

> Parameters cannot be used for the following constructs, as these form part of the query structure that is compiled into a query plan:
>
> - property keys; so, MATCH (n) WHERE n.$param = 'something' is invalid
> - relationship types
> - labels

I built the string myself like so:

```
'WHERE a.id = ' + userId + ' AND b.id = ' + todoId +
```